# Sqlite3 Blob to UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uiimage, blob

Hello I have a Sqlite3 database created in my computer and I want to read that database in my Iphone. 
The following code works in Iphone simulator, but doesn't work in a real device, it appears to be some problem related to devices architectures (MacBook vs Iphone). 
The problem is when I read the data and try to convert it to UIImage the data doesn't seem to be correct because the result is a UIImageView in blank instead of the representation of the Image. In the simulator in works nice.

```
-(IBAction) findPhoto{

databaseName = @"memoryDB.sqlite";

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];



    int res = 0;

    res = sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, nil);

    if(res == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access

        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithString:@"SELECT * FROM Fotos"];

        const char *sqlStatement = [querySQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if((res = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the data from the result row


                UIImage *image;

                NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 1) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 1)];

                if(data == nil)
                    NSLog(@"No image found.");
                else
                    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];     
                //

                NSLog(@"width: %f,height: %f",image.size.width, image.size.height);

                UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                [self.view addSubview:imgView];

            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        sqlite3_close(database); 

    }
}
```

I include the database (DB) in the project, and the DB was created in my MacBook. Is that the problem? It is possible to convert the data to the correct format?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**This is not proper way. to store image in the database.**

**you should save it to NSDocumentDirectory.**

**and just store the name of image into the table of db.**

**so its easy to get the name of image name from table and get image from documentdirectory. and its very faster then getting image from db.**

Comment: Thank you. I will try that, but I have some problem with my application size. I want it to be less than 20 MB. Do it as you recommend I will have the paths to the photos and I will have the photos... instead of having only the photos

Comment: if you store it db then also it will increase the size of DB.

Comment: I don't think it's incorrect to store raw binary data in a db. That's why BLOB (and TINYBLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, etc.) exists. It has it's drawbacks, of course, but it helps sometimes and it's a resource that should be used in some cases.